# Слетает локальный gulp 4 после установки других пакетов локально, как исправить?

Tags: gulp, npm

Поставил gulp 4 глобально, ставлю его локально для проекта, но стоит мне поставить какой-нибудь ещё пакет в этом проекте как он сразу слетает и просит его установить.

Comment: Очень поверхностное описание проблемы, сложно ответить на ваш вопрос. Что видите в терминале? Пишутся ли какие-то ошибки? Что значит слетает? Просит - какой текст именно? Какими командами устанавливаете? Куда?

Answer (score 0):

Создан ли в Вашем проекте package.json, который отслеживает зависимости?
Если нет то создайте: `npm init`, желательно устанавливать gulp после создания package.json и после установки дополнительных модулей выполнять npm up.
Итак:

```
npm init
npm install gulp --save-dev
npm up
```

Comment: package.json есть, сделал как вы описали безуспешно.

Comment: и такая проблема только с gulp 4